# How can I remove these values on Barchart

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I would like to remove the red circled numbers on my Barchart. I am using the danielgindi library.

It shouldn't be very hard but i can't find it on the net.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you using `danielgindi` or `ios-charts`? Either use proper tags or fix your question body.

Comment: It's the same ! 

Try to read well next time : https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Look for: `setDrawValueAboveBar()` (or something similar). Source from Android Version Doc (which should be similar): https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Specific-chart-settings

Comment: Why should I? You ask the question, dont use different name for the same thing to confuse as many people as possible (why should I care about the library author?).

Comment: EveryBody use ios-charts to talk about de danielgindi library on stackOverflow, click on the ios-charts tag and you'll see !

Comment: @Larme thanks but this allow to draw the value above or not the Bar but it didn't remove it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question Solved :

```
barChart.maxVisibleValueCount = 0
```

;)